# Safety of concurrent read and write to Android internal storage file

Tags: android, file-io, concurrency, internal-storage

I have a file store in Android internal storage.  It's possible that one thread might be writing to the file while another thread attempts to read it.  Do I need to ensure that these two operations do not overlap?  If so, generally speaking, what are my options?